# Copying a Java Dynamic Web Project and renaming it to new one causes the error in Tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

In eclipse whenever we copying a java dynamic web project into new one by renaming it and trying to run the new copied project in tomcat server it causes below error:

"Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost.
Multiple Contexts have a path of "/CopiedParentDynamicProjectName".

Anyone have idea how to overcome this tomcat error after copying the dynamicwebproject while running it server.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Open Servers folder and click on server.xml file.

Step 2) Scroll all the way down to find following code

```
<Context docBase="spring-security-demo-01-base-app" path="/spring-security-demo" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-security-demo-01-base-app"/>
  <Context docBase="spring-security-demo-01-base-app" path="/spring-security-demo" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-security-demo-01-base-app"/>
```

Step 3) See the duplicate entry and delete one.

Step 4) Change the path so that we have following code.

```
<Context docBase="spring-security-demo-01-base-app" path="/spring-security-demo-01-base-app" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-security-demo-01-base-app"/><Context docBase="spring-security-demo-01-base-app" path="/spring-security-demo" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-security-demo-01-base-app"/>
```

Step 5) Save the file.

Step 6) Problem is solved.